# Force PCIe SSD to be /dev/sdb on linux install

Tags: linux, hp-proliant, dell-poweredge, ssd

Is there any options to force the PCIe SSD during install to be not /dev/sda? I was hoping to reserve the SSD to be limited to be only /var but the grub loader fails each time when I try to set the bootable partition to be /dev/sdc2 (sdb is usb install drive).

I have been installing on Dell r610 and HP DL385 G6 servers using both CentOS 6.6 and Ubuntu 14 and the PCI device always shows up before the raid devices.

Comment: read about udev  and udev.rules

Comment: This looks very much like an XY question. Your problem is not that your SSD is called /dev/sda but what you want to use it for. Your SSD being assigned to /dev/sda does not prevent using it exclusively for the /var filesystem.

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt, maybe because of the age of the bios, but it doesn't boot from PCIe, so even if I install it there (which will happen during install) it will fail when it comes time to actually boot.

Comment: I fail to see what all this has to do with the device names your various storage devices are assigned. You need to install your operating system and boot loader on a device your BIOS is able to boot from. IIUC in your case that means a RAID device which you have in your server alongside the PCIe SSD you mention in your question. Whether that RAID is named /dev/sda, /dev/sdb or /dev/sdc is irrelevant. If there's a problem with installing Linux on your RAID you need to fix that problem. Trying to rename the devices is unlikely to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't eff with udev rules for this. Modify your install scripts (preseed or kickstart) to ignore `/dev/sda`.

See: [Consistent Install Disk Selection in RHEL Kickstart](https://serverfault.com/questions/615678/consistent-install-disk-selection-in-rhel-kickstart/615682#615682)

Also, is there any way you can run a network install. USB installation of the OS is fraught because of [SCSI enumeration issues](https://serverfault.com/questions/699038/proliant-dl380p-gen8-debian-booting/699088#699088).

Comment: Thanks Edward, I will look at preseed, it looks interesting. I haven't ever done a network install, but there isn't any technical reason I can't do it. For what it is worth I switched the PCI Slot I was using to be the last one where PCI 1&2 were for the SAS and PCI 3 was for the SSD. When I booted into the CentOS installer the SSD was recognized as /dev/sdd.